# 8″ × 10″ pages with memoir

Tags: memoir

I have been using memoir's page settings more or less via experimentation with the help of a manual. I may as well ask for a different guide, too. Peter's documentation is very detailed, but also hard for typesetting amateurs to follow.

Right now, I am stuck. Many printers offer 8″ × 10″ paper, but it's not a standard stock size in memoir.

I started experimenting with the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}

\settrimmedsize{10in}{8in}{*}
\setlength{\trimtop}{0pt}
\setlength{\trimedge}{\stockwidth}
\addtolength{\trimedge}{-\paperwidth}

\settypeblocksize{8.5in}{*}{*}
\setulmargins{2.5cm}{*}{*}
\setlrmargins{0.75in}{*}{*}

\setmarginnotes{17pt}{85pt}{\onelineskip}

\setheadfoot{\onelineskip}{2\onelineskip}
\setheaderspaces{*}{2\onelineskip}{*}

\checkandfixthelayout

\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{layout}

\begin{document}

\layout

\end{document}
```

which gives

```
pdfinfo 01-test.pdf | grep 'Page size'
Page size:       612 x 792 pts (letter)
```

(This is 8.5″ × 11″, not 8″ × 10″. My printer won't accept it, so this is the end of my attempts.)

Can I please ask for a naive memoir construction guide? I am making up numbers that are intentionally tutorial rather than typographically superior.

- I want (from left to right) my 8 inches to be unwriteable outer-margin 0.75″, margin-note to be 1.25″, text block to be 5″, and spine margin to be 1″. This adds to 8″.
- I want (from top to bottom) my 10″ to be 0.5″ to header, another 0.25″ to text block, then 7.25″ of textblock, 0.5″ to page, and 1.5″ to bottom. This adds up to 10″.

Comment: If you intend to print on 8x10 stock you need to speficy that as a stock. What you're doing here is trimming the standard stock size to 8x10 but that is still the default stock size (letter). Settrimmed just allows you to design a different document size onto a given stock size.

Comment: indeed.  but I still need a mechanism to request a specific paper stock, too --- an example.

Comment: `\setstocksize{10in}{8in} \settrimmedsize{\stockheight}{\stockwidth}{*} ` should to the trick

Comment: it does work.  thanks, daleif.  the rest would be great, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the process is:

- Set the stocksize (either by class option or you can use `\setstocksize`)
- Set the size of the textblock with `\settypeblocksize`.
- Position the textblock on the page with `\setlrmargins` for left to right position and `\setulmargins` for vertical positioning.
- fiddle with the minor layout parameters such as header/footer spacing

`memoir` has a variety of macros in addition to the above for accomplishing the same tasks.

```
% memstocksizeprob.tex  SE 646596

\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}

\setstocksize{10in}{8in} %% PW added
\settrimmedsize{10in}{8in}{*}
%\setlength{\trimtop}{0pt} %% PW deleted
%\setlength{\trimedge}{\stockwidth} %% PW deleted
%\addtolength{\trimedge}{-\paperwidth} %% PW deleted

\settypeblocksize{8.5in}{*}{*} % but you wanted the textblock to be 7.25 by 5in
\settypeblocksize{7.25in}{5in}{*} %% PW added
\setulmargins{2.5cm}{*}{*}
%\setlrmargins{0.75in}{*}{*} %% why set the spine margin to 0.75 in when you want it to be 1in?
\setlrmargins{1in}{*}{*} 
\setmarginnotes{17pt}{85pt}{\onelineskip}

\setheadfoot{\onelineskip}{2\onelineskip}
\setheaderspaces{*}{2\onelineskip}{*}

\checkandfixthelayout

\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{layout}

\begin{document}

\layout

\end{document}
```

I have only dealt with the main layout, the more minor details are up to you.